# Iterate over json Array using Power shell

Tags: json, powershell

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$Path="C:\Users\Desktop\test.json"
$json=(Get-Content $Path | ConvertFrom-Json).parameters.FileArray 
//FileArray is array name in json file
$demo=$json.GetType().FullName //System.Object[]

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem "D:\A\DF\ls\" -Include $json|ForEach Object{$_} -Recurse){

Write-Output $file.BaseName 
Write-Output $file.FullName

Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2LinkedService -DataFactoryName "adfg1" - ResourceGroupName "bgc" -Name $file.BaseName -DefinitionFile $file.FullName -Force
}
```

Json I am using test.json:
    {
    "parameters":
    {
    "FileArray": [
    "ABC.json",
    "DEF.json"]
    }
    }

Exception I am getting is:
    ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert 
    the "-Recurse" value of type "System.String" to 
    type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".

What I am expecting(Names of files):
ABC.json
DEF.json

```
Any help how it can be handled.
How I can iterate over array values from json.
P.S: I am beginner in powershell
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem "D:\A\DF\ls\" -Include $json -Recurse)) {

$file.BaseName
$file.FullName

}
```

I don't see why you would need `ForEach Object{$_}` , the `-include` accepts an array

Example code:

```
$jsonfile = '{"parameters":
             { "FileArray": [ "ABC.json", "DEF.json"] } }' | ConvertFrom-Json
$json = $jsonfile.parameters.FileArray

foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -Include $json -Recurse)) {
    $file.BaseName
    $file.FullName
}
```

Example output:

```
ABC
C:\temp\example-folder\ABC.json
DEF
C:\temp\example-folder\DEF.json
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not printing json file names in output.

Comment: I changed the path in my code to "D:\A\DF\ls\" for `Get-ChildItem` like in your script. Does it print anything now?

Comment: U have not used write-output also. I have used still it is not printing anything. I tried to debug as well.Control is not even coming to Write-Output line of code

Comment: added an example with 2 files created manually on my hard drive. I'm using my c:\temp folder. You should change this of course

Comment: without using write-output how you are able to print it. I am still not able to get names of files in output

Comment: You don't need to specify Write-Output, but you can. Not specifying anything is the same as `$file.FullName | Out-Default | Out-Host` (which is the terminal)

Comment: This can only mean that you don't have any files in "D:\A\DF\ls\" that match your FileArray?